# Using multiple headers in a PHP file_get_contents() call

Tags: php

I'm trying to send a POST request to the PayPal API using no external libraries (hence no cURL). Instead, I'm using `file_get_contents()`. When trying to combine the Basic Authentication header with the Content-Type header, I get a 400 (Bad-Request). Please see the code snippet below.

```
// The Basic Authentication Credential Encoding
$creds = sprintf('Authorization: Basic %s',
        base64_encode($CLIENT_ID . ':' . $CLIENT_SECRET));

// Combining the two headers into an array
$header = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    $creds
);

// Creating the context to use with file_get_contents
$ctx = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'display_errors' => true,
        'protocol_version'  => '1.1',
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => implode("\r\n", $header), // Imploding the header array and adding \r\n
        'content' => json_encode($postBody)
    )
));

$res = file_get_contents($urlString, FALSE, $ctx);
```

Interestingly enough, when I remove the `$creds` variable from the `$header` array, I obtain a 401 (Unauthorized), and when I remove the Content-Type from the `$header`, I get a 416 (Unsupported Media).

How to I combine the two headers successfully?

Comment: The examples in the PHP manual use `\r\n` after every header, not just as inner separator. Perhaps that's relevant.

Comment: ^This is exactly how we use it in the project. Example:
```
        $headers = "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $key\r\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately, I have also tried this already. It gives me a bad request response as well. Is there anything else you recommend me to try?

Comment: To diagnose the issue, you can leave PayPal aside by now and test it against a script of your own. That way you can verify what changes in the receiving end when using different options.